# What Is The Difference Between suppress_errors() And hide_errors() in $wpdb?

Tags: customization, database

What is the difference between the suppress_errors() function and the hide_errors() functionin wpdb class?

What is the use of each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `suppress_errors()` hides errors during the database bootstrapping
- `hide_errors()` hides SQL errors

Comment: So, the setting to hide errors is set by default right? We use hide_errors(false) only when we need to show errors?

Comment: Yes, hide errors is set by default. We use `$wpdb->show_errors();` when we need to show them. For reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class