# How can I make wordpress suppress mysql errors?

Tags: mysql, errors, wp-config, configuration

Wordpress has two functions related to SQL queries and their errors as mentioned in [What Is The Difference Between suppress_errors() And hide_errors() in $wpdb?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/what-is-the-difference-between-suppress-errors-and-hide-errors-in-wpdb)

From what I've read setting `WP_DEBUG` to `false` in `wp-config.php` will set `hide_errors()` so that mySql errors aren't show - but if the site can't connect to the database you'll still error:

> WordPress database error: [MySQL server has gone away]`

Without modifying the core file `wp-includes/wp-db.php` and setting the line ~69 to
`var $suppress_errors = true;`
(which is what I've done for now), how can I set `suppress_errors` to false without modifying the core?